Extruding breaks geometry
I want to extrude along normals this object: 
The result should be like this, but even. This action breaks the geometry which is why result is not even. 
I think the problem is in the uneven cutting up, but i can't fix it. I tried to add and reduce geometry, but it didn't help.
Blend file - 
Thanks in advance!

Any time you just cut across a grid of quads at an arbitrary angle, ignoring edge flow completely, the result will be ugly. Search: 3d edge flow topology poles It's worth studying, and the knowledge will help you in all your designs moving forward. This is universal to all polygon modeling software.

Your topology is too dense, you should simplify it:

Extrude along normals:

Bevel the edges and give it a Subdivision Surface modifier:

